# Bulding polkadot (release-v0.9.24) fails while compiling a dependency (prost-build v0.10.4)

Tags: polkadot, relay-chain, build, compilation

I'm trying to build Polkadot as a relay chain for a tutorial but compiling one of its dependencies fails! I may be missing some tools. Could you help?
Platform: MacOS (Intel)

```
Compiling prost-build v0.10.4
error: failed to run custom build command for `prost-build v0.10.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `<redacted_path>/polkadot/target/release/build/prost-build-c6015cab4894bbe1/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=<redacted_path>/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/prost-build-0.10.4/third-party/protobuf/cmake
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
  CMAKE_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CMAKE = None
  CMAKE = None
  running: "cmake" "<redacted_path>/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/prost-build-0.10.4/third-party/protobuf/cmake" "-Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<redacted_path>/polkadot/target/release/build/prost-build-330684d335a6d019/out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -arch x86_64" "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -arch x86_64" "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fPIC -m64 -arch x86_64" "-DCMAKE_ASM_COMPILER=/usr/bin/cc" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '
  failed to execute command: No such file or directory (os error 2)
  is `cmake` not installed?

  build script failed, must exit now', <redacted_path>/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cmake-0.1.48/src/lib.rs:975:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

I have previously built the `substrate-node-template` project successfully.
From the error it looks like I have no `cmake` installed but I have installed the Apple's developers tools and in general I've used this machine for development, including compiling generic Rust code.

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Note I've also covered some of the Substrate tutorials prior to the one about starting my own relay chain (and connecting parachains to it) https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-relay/

Comment: I also updated my rust toolchain to the latest version at time of writing and still no luck - 1.62.0 for stable and 1.64.0-nightly for nightly.

Comment: Hi, can you try install cmake (e.g brew install cmake) and then should works.

Comment: Hi @pepoviola thank you for the suggestion! Do you have an idea why that changed in `prost-build v0.10.4`? I'm currently building the `substrate-node-template` without any issue and it successfully compiles `prost-build v0.9.0`. So I try to understand before installing additional tools

Comment: To answer my own question - probably this commit in `prost-build` started requiring `cmake` - "build: Remove bundled protoc and build from source" https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost/commit/fc9fbd9823f93774004975f7794dac112a2ff4ef

Comment: @pepoviola thank you for the comment! It encouraged me to dig deeper and I found that I can download a pre-built `protoc` instead of having to build it each time with `cmake`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most frictionless way to fix this is by installing `cmake`.

---

Alternatively, provide a pre-built `protoc` to the build process.

More context about [prost](https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost):

> PROST! a Protocol Buffers implementation for the Rust Language

Specifically,

> prost-build makes it easy to generate Rust code from .proto files as part of a Cargo build

To compile [prost-build](https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost/tree/master/prost-build) you can either provide `cmake` or precompiled `protoc`. Luckily, the prost-build Readme links to the [installation instructions of `protoc`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf#protocol-compiler-installation) where you can find a pre-build binary for your system.

Using this binary with an environment variable lets cargo build the dependency (`prost-build`) without having to also build `protoc`.

`PROTOC=/path/to/protoc cargo build --release`

Comment: Updated docs for troubleshooting here: https://docs.substrate.io/main-docs/install/troubleshooting/#installing-cmake-or-protobuf-for-m1-macos-users

Answer (score 0):

This will fix by just installing c-make.